# Populating buttons with name based on login type in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have models as follows:

```
public class UserDetails
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool Truck { get; set; }
        public bool Car { get; set; }
        public bool Bus { get; set; }
}

public class TransportDetails
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url{ get; set; }
}
```

I also defined a list that contains user details as follows:

```
public List<UserDetails> GetAllUserDetails()
 {
     List<UserDetails> userDetails = new List<UserDetails>
     {
        new UserDetails
         {
                    Id = 1,
                    Username = "admin",
                    Password = "123",
                    Truck = false,
                    Car = true,
                    Bus = true
                },
                new UserDetails
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Username = "superadmin",
                    Password = "123",
                    Truck = true,
                    Car = false,
                    Bus = true
                }
            };

     return userDetails;
}
```

The app works as follows :

- The user logins with a credentials.
- Based on his credentials, it is determined which property he has access to, either truck, car or bus. And he is directed to the MainPage.
- When redirected to the MainPage, buttons should appear with the properties' values that the user has access to. 
  In other words, the buttons should have name as defined in the Model **TransportDetails**

So far, this has been done:

```
public void CheckLogin()
        {
            UserData userData = new UserData();

            allUsers = new List<UserDetails>();

            allUsers = userData.GetAllUserDetails();

            if (allUsers.Any(x => x.Username.Equals(Username) && x.Password.Equals(Password)))
            {
                var user = allUsers.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(Username) && x.Password.Equals(Password)).First();
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new PortalPage(user));
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Invalid credentials", "OK");
            }
        }
```

I want to get buttons to appeared dynamically based on what property is true in the model UserDetails once a user has logged in. Then, when the buttons appeared based on what is true for this user, I want the button name and button value (url) from the TransportDetails model.

Could someone advise me on how to achieve this please ?

Comment: What data is in TrasnportDetails. Is the Name and Id is same as UserDetails. url could be webAddress, local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

if (user.Truck) {
  Button truck = new Button();
  var transport = transports.Where(t => t.Name == "truck").First();
  truck.Text = transport.Name;
  truck.Clicked +=  (sender, e) => { Device.OpenUrl(transport.Url); };
  stack.Children.Add(truck);
}

// repeat for other types
```

if you modify your UserDetails class

```
public class UserDetails
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public List<TransportDetail> Transport { get; set; }
}
```

then you could just do this

```
StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

foreach (var t in user.Transport) {    
  Button btn = new Button();
  btn.Text = t.Name;
  btn.Clicked +=  (sender, e) => { Device.OpenUrl(t.Url); };
  stack.Children.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: I want to make it efficient.. What if I have several properties like cycle,bike,  etc.. ? Do I need to repeat an `if-statement` for each property ?

Comment: Yes.  As long as you're storing them as individual bools in your User record.  If you want something more efficient, just store a list of TransportType values and iterate through them.

Comment: Should I create a model of TransportType ?

Comment: Your User class should have a List<TransportDetails>, not a hardcoded set of bools

Comment: Could you advise how should I modify my `GetAllUserDetails()` for each user ? Also, how can I check so as to populate my buttons dynamically ? 

I'm sorry I'm asking too much.. but I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your Model.
For every User you should have a `ObservableCollection<TransportDetail> transportDetail`

```
public class UserDetails
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<TransportDetails> TransportDetails{get;set;}
}
```

then you should add to TransportDetails only transport enabled to the user.

At this point, I suggest to use a ListView. On every ViewCell you should have a Button. Bind your properties to this Button. Fill the ViewCell with `trasportDetail` List

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: I need to set which user has access to which property; like a user can have access to Truck & Car.. Another can have access to Bus only.. and so on.